# Creating custom Fabric executable

Tags: python, fabric

I am looking for a way to call Fabric from a script inside one of my packages, essentially turning it into an alias for `fab -f /path/to/my/installed/package/scripts/fabfile.py`.

Is there a standard way to do that, or should I just call it from `subprocess`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have complete solution for you problem, but you would need to start off using the package **pkg_resources** to perfectly identify the location of your fabric file inside the other project.

In the following example I've create a small testing project called **hellofabric** containg a file called **testfab.py** (please ignore fabfile.py in the root folder of the project, this comes from my python bootstrap script). Here is the file structure.

```
.
├── fabfile.py
├── hellofabric
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── testfab.py
│   └── version.txt
├── hellofabric.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

**testfab.py** contains the following code.

```
import fabric.api as fab 


@fab.task
def hellofabric():
    fab.local("echo Hello from fabric")
```

Next step would be to create a dist file of this project (*python setup.py sdist*), and try to install that distribution file inside of your destination project. Once I did that I was able to execute the following which executed the fabric script.

```
>>> from hellofabric import testfab
>>> testfab.hellofabric()
[localhost] local: echo Hello from fabric
Hello from fabric
>>>
```

Hope this what you are looking for.